# Node js: using model-like code outside of the model

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to write a small api with Facebook authentication and as I'm new to node.js I'm just a little confused as to how I should structure this.

I have a route called auth.js that looks like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var crypto = require('crypto');
var rp = require('request-promise');

var router = express.Router();

router.post('/', function(req, res) {
    rp('https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=' + req.body.fbAccessToken).then(function(body) {
        var json = JSON.parse(body);
        if(json.error) { res.status(403).send(json.error.message); }

        var user = new User({
            userId: json.id,
            fbAccessToken: req.body.fbAccessToken,
            apiAccessToken: crypto.randomBytes(64).toString('hex'),
            firstName: json.first_name,
            lastName: json.last_name,
            email: json.email
        });

        user.save(function(err) {
            if (err) throw err;
            return user.userId;
        });
    }).then(function(userId) {
        res.status(201).send('something');
    }).catch(function(err) {
        res.status(403).send(err);
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

When the route recieves a post it takes the Facebook token from the request and checks if it is legit using the Facebook graph API. (Apologies if the Promise stuff looks a little funky too, I'm trying to learn that as well).

Anyway, I have a User model and a user.js route too. What I want to know is if the User creation that happens in my auth route here should be moved to the User model and the model functions called from here somehow? Via the user route maybe?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Yes and yes.  I think user stuff can go under /user and it is cleaner if the user creation is in its own module.

BTW did you see [fbgraph](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fbgraph)?

Comment: I don't need fbgraph thanks, I'm only making a single GET to the graph API. Would the user creation code go in my model or route and how can I call it from auth.js?